# Using ASTTransformation to "remove" def to change Scope in Groovy script

Tags: compiler-construction, groovy, transformation, abstract-syntax-tree

However strange it sounds I need to modify some Groovy code by modifying how variables are being created.

I have previously solved some other related problem with ASTTransformation when I needed to "mimic" the Use/Category-functionality by modifying the code to invoke my custom special method.

What I need now to do is this:

I need the following type of code:

```
def a = "X";
Integer b = 1;
```

to behave as this code:

```
a = "X";
b = 1;
```

The difference is that the second example is "stored" in the binding-scope.

Some context:

I'm writing a groovy template engine, where I have some code-fragment (provided by the user) that gets placed into a method in a groovy class / file, which I then compile. When I run the code-fragment/method I need its created variables to be accessible via the Binding-mechanisme.

I hope someone can help me in the correct direction..

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

(thanks for the great answer)

I have another question:

I think it can work when I modify all declarations, but it would be better if I only modified the ones in the most outer block. An example:

```
Object aMethod() {
  def a = 1; //should be modified
  def b = 2; //should be modified
  if (expression) {
    def c = 2; //does not need to be modified
  }
}
```

Do you know how it is possible to detect if the declaration is in the most outmost block (main block) in the method body?

-Morten

Comment: here is working code: https://github.com/mbknor/play/blob/f1792dc6bd17c33bb6e753bf9fd0b29eaab4ad75/framework/src/play/template2/compile/GTGroovyVariableScopeTransformer.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to replace the DeclarationExpressions in the AST with a BinaryExpression. You will notice the DeclarationExpression is a BinaryExpression, so you simply have to copy over everything. Also don't forget to call setSourcePosition on the new node using the old node to ensure the line numbers are right. The Expressions are stored in ExpressionStatements, making it not too difficult to replace them.

As for in which phase to operate... I strongly recommend to do this before the variable scopes are set, then you have less work and you won't have to delete the many references to the variables in AST later. You could do this for example in CONVERSION.

One more word on the semantic changes you introduce with this:

(1) String a = 1; a = 2; in this code example you will get two times a String being stored in a. This is essentially because for every assignment Groovy will do a Groovy style cast and that includes the transformation to String here. This is done because the variable is typed. If it is not typed such transformations will not happen. That is the case for "def", but also for variables in the binding. Meaning your binding would store the integers 1 and 2, not the Strings.

(2) The other point is scopes. If I understand you right, then you want to make all variables global. Programs written with the context of having only a block wide scope for the variable may then behave strange. This can happen especially for variables in Groovy Closures if the Groovy Closures are executed not synchronously, but for example a later, more detached point in your program

(3) The last point is a change in the usage of the MOP. The get the value of a local variable we don't use the MOP, instead we do it directly. If you move the local variables into the global scope, you will have to go through the complete MOP to get the values. If at some point you have a program element capturing the call and repeating on its own, you will have get a different program.

Maybe that doesn't matter in your case... I just wanted you to be aware of these things.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer! I did see the "connection" between DeclarationExpressions and BinaryExpression, but I didn't know how to use/apply it. thanks again. When it comes to scoping, it is not a problem (due to how the different code-fragments are composed to interact).

Comment: Please see updated question. If you don't know, i'll accept your great answer anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Your updated question was: Do you know how it is possible to detect if the declaration is in the most outmost block (main block) in the method body?

Well, I would probably do the following as the most easy way. Get the MethodNode from the AST, and the containing code using getCode(). If it is an ExpressionStatement, then you change it, if it contains a DeclarationExpression. If it is a BlockStatement, then you go through all the statements in there and change them if needed like with the single one.

This solution is easy, but doesn't catch for example a declaration in a while loop.

If you are ok for a more safe but also more complicated solution, then I suggest using one of the visitors Groovy provides. You could count the nesting level using an int, by overwriting visitBlockStatment you increase the count by 1. Then you overwrite visitExpressionStatement. If the nesting level is 0 and the statement contains a DeclarationExpression, then you make your transform, otherwise not... in which case you also don't need to go deeper in the tree. Now for the entering method, usually visitMethod. If the method code is an BlockStatement, then you start with level -1, and just continue with super, otherwise you start with level 0.

As for the visitor... the general purpose one is ClassCodeVisitor, which makes sense as I described it above actually only if you want to transform the code like that from multiple methods. Or you use for example CodeVisistorSupport, but then you have to have that method init logic for the level extra.